# MySQL connector/C++ error "Unresolved external symbol _get_driver_instance" in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

I know this topic is common on this forum, but after all researching for solution I still cannot make it work.

I did everything from Developer Guide:

- Linked Boost libraries
- Linked Connector/C++ static library
- Switched from Debug to Release
- Installed binary (I really don't want to build from source unless I absolutly have to)

When I am trying to build an example code, which looks like this:

```
/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
/*
Include directly the different
headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
(and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message'..." << endl;
try {
sql::Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;
sql::Statement *stmt;
sql::ResultSet *res;
/* Create a connection */
driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
/* Connect to the MySQL test database */
con->setSchema("test");
stmt = con->createStatement();
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
while (res->next()) {
cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
/* Access column data by alias or column name */
cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
/* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
}
delete res;
delete stmt;
delete con;
} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}
cout << endl;
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MySQL test, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>MySQL test.cpp
1>Info: Boost.Config is older than your compiler version - probably nothing bad will happen - but you may wish to look for an update Boost version.  Define BOOST_CONFIG_SUPPRESS_OUTDATED_MESSAGE to suppress this message.
1>MySQL test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _get_driver_instance
1>C:\Users\rafal\source\repos\MySQL test\Release\MySQL test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "MySQL test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Boost libraries version is 1_66_0, that's the latest one.

Configuration Properties / C/C++ / General / Additional Include Directories: C:\boost; C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9\include

Configuration Properties / C/C++ / Preprocessor / Preprocessor Definicions: WIN32l; NDEBUG; _CONSOLE; CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC=

Configuration Properties / Linker / General / Additional Library Directories: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9\lib\opt

Configuration Properties / Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies: mysqlcppconn-static.lib

Configuration Properties / Linker / Command Line:

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBHX6.png)
[Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isYpi.png)

What can I do to not get this error?

Comment: You need also the MySQL C connector (not C++), Connector C++ is a wrapper around C connector.

Comment: So that's mean that I have to include C connector too?

Comment: Even when I included C connector, it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you're using C connector as a DLL then you need to link with libmysql.lib, otherwise link with libmysqlclient.lib. You need to define preprocessor variable MYSQLCLIENT_STATIC_LINKING in C++ connector before compiling if you want to use libmysqlclient.lib. By default this variable is not defined which means your program needs to be linked to libmysql.lib. I'm not sure that I got the lib names right...

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.

Comment: Well you're not linking it properly. You need to provide more data if you want someone to help you: how you built the connectors, directory locations and linker command line.

Comment: Connectors are from binary version, rest is posted in edit.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I haven't noticed the options you used. _Configuration Properties / Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies: mysqlcppconn-static.lib_ This is the C++ connector lib. C++ connector is a wrapper around C connector. You need to add **libmysql.lib** (C connector used as a DLL) or **mysqlclient.lib** (C connector statically linked in). You need to set MYSQLCLIENT_STATIC_LINKING for C++ connector depending on which C connector lib you are linking with. But, if you downloaded the binaries for C++ connector, there's only one option for C connector, I don't remember which.

Comment: But you can anyway try each one of **libmysql.lib** and **mysqlclient.lib**, one of them will work and the other one not. If you're using C connector as a DLL then make sure that libmysql.dll is accessible to your executable in path or the same directory.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try this.

Comment: Still getting the same error. I will try to build the connector. If it doesn't work either, I will give up.

Comment: _"Still getting the same error"_. Did you find **libmysql.lib** and **mysqlclient.lib** files and set their path in the linker options? I see that your output says _"Build started: Project: MySQL test, Configuration: Release Win32"_ but there's a linker option _"/DEBUG"_. Are you mixing debug and release parameters? The binaries you have might have only release versions of the libraries...

Comment: No, everything I did was in release configuration.

Comment: But you have a _"/DEBUG"_ option in linker options. That's not release. Go to properties of RELEASE version and post the linker command line.

Comment: get_driver_instance() is a function from C++ connector. Event that's not working properly...

Comment: I added screens of command lines for debug and release configurations, check it out if you want.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at it.

Comment: _"/DEBUG"_ is ok, that's just generation of PDB file.

Comment: So, what can I do about this?

Comment: What is in directory "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9\lib\opt"? Is mysqlcppconn-static.lib there?

Comment: And did you use **32 bit** C++ connector? Check that it isn't **64 bit** one.

Comment: Because your program is 32 bit (Release Win32).

Comment: Nah, I think that it is 64bit

Comment: That might be it. Either you change your program to 64 bit build or download 32-bit C++ connector. I've just downloaded it: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/

Comment: And you can't use both **libmysql.lib** and **mysqlclient.lib** at the same time, only one. Try with one and if it doesn't work use the other one. And also C connector needs to be 32 bit or 64 bit the same as everything else.

Comment: I tried them separately, didn't work either.

Comment: Never mind C connector now, the unresolved symbol get_driver_instance() is from C++ connector, fix that first. When this error is gone then try with libmysql.lib and mysqlclient.lib. Download the 32-bit C++ connector, install it and set the linker options to point to it.

Comment: I found a video that shows how to build c++ connector in debug version for 64 bit, gonna try this first. Give me some time.

Comment: You can download the binaries, don't build it if you never did that, you'll lose hours, trust me. And your program is 32-bit: _"Release Win32"_ you need 32-bit C++ connector. Anyway it's easier to change your program to 64 bit than to build C++ connector from source.

Comment: I have all MySQL server in 64 bit, does this mean that I have to reinstall?

Comment: No. Just change your program to 64 bit then, to make it work. When it works later you can play with it and build 32-bit. **OR** don't download Windows MSI installer, download ZIP archive and just unpack it somewhere, not to the MySQL installation directories.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you installed 64-bit MySQL, always use connector in a ZIP file because you can unpack it into your working directory for your Visual studio project and it will not interfere with any MySQL installations.

Comment: Even with 32 bit version doesn't work.

Comment: I see now that MySQL C++ connector binaries are VC12, so they can be used only in Visual studio 2013, not 2017. But that doesn't explain the errror. Are you sure you've set the paths properly?
But that maybe doesn't matter any more, for Visual studio 2017 you'll have to build it from source. You will need Boost library for that...

Comment: Already got them, accually you can't even try to build without boost included.

Comment: Yes you can, C connector doesn't need Boost, Only C++ connector. And you **don't need to build Boost**, C++ connector needs only Boost header files.

Comment: I know about it, don't worry 

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfyXHKYaNZ4 this guy shows it preety well.

Comment: Well, instead of making a video I've made Perl scripts which build all automatically. :)

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you to send me those?

Comment: Yes, I can send it to you. But later in the evening (I'm in CET time zone), I'm at work now. Give me an e-mail address.

Comment: OK, will e-mail the files and instructions in the evening.

Comment: I will wait impaciently 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Installed binary (I really don't want to build from source unless I absolutly have to)*

You're gonna absolutely have to.

There are no official binaries for Visual studio 2017 (VC 15) at the moment of writing of this answer. As I've checked in official downloads, binaries are for Visual studio 2013 - VC 12.